# What is the name for this in Design Pattern?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

```
class MyType
{
public:
    A ( unsigned _a ) : a (_a-1)
    {

    }
    operator unsigned& () 
    {
        return a;
    }
    operator const unsigned () const
    {
        return a;
    }
    unsigned a; 
};
```

In the above example, I created a class MyType which is comprised of just one unsigned integer.

is there a design pattern name for MyType? It is a unsigned integer and it could be use as one. But just with a different name

Comment: What is the value of this over `typedef unsigned MyType`?

Comment: I would call it a "wrapper" where conversion happen implicitly.

Comment: I am rather sceptical about the usefullness of this pattern... it's not obvious anyway.

Comment: I'm curious why you initialize `a` with `a (_a-1)`.

Comment: @birryree So when the user passes in 0 it wraps around to `UINT_MAX` possibly?

Comment: @Dai Haoci, go to the answer that you like, on the left there is a number of votes with two arrows up and down. Below it there is a check mark with white color. Click it and it turns green. That way you would officially accept one answer as the answer to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what the design pattern name is, but there is a use for it.

It can be useful if you have a set of classes that all implement that same member functions, and you want to treat them all in the same way. Some of these classes contain simple types like `int` and `unsigned`, while others contain more complicated class/struct types.

The goal is to allow "boxed" primitive types to act like the more complicated "real" class types. This is especially useful when these classses can all be used as template parameters within a group of template classes or functions (i.e., when all of the classes inherit the same base interface class(es)).

Comment: The question asked what the name is. By reading this accepted answer, I expected to learn what the name is. So, what is the name of this technique?

Answer (score 1):

Bruce Eckel does something similar in [Thinking in C++](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html) on page 354, '"Constructors" for built-in types' paragraph.
Such a design could be useful (as Bruce states) to strictly control the initialization of the encapsulated type.
However I don't know of any names for it.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a known design pattern.  What is the point of that code?  It's a type that acts just like an unsigned integer, so why not just use an unsigned integer?

Comment: It's like a unsigned integer, but with some tweak.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a design pattern at all.
It is an "idiom" which only can be used in C++.
Design Patterns are usually language agnostic and can be implemented in any language that supports the underlying principles like delegation / inheritance.

Answer (score -2):

This is not a design pattern at all, because a design pattern describes interaction between several classes, and you only have one.

Comment: No, not really. A design pattern describes a solution to a design problem. Classes need not be involved.

Comment: @Fernandes I see no design problem here so far, no context for the problem and thus no solution.

Comment: The comment wasn't about you saying it's not a design pattern. It was about the *reason* you gave for it not being a design pattern. The reason you gave is invalid because that's not what determines what qualifies as a design pattern.